# UITextView within UIScrollView - Dynamic Heights?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, height, uitextview

I have a UIView which contains a UIScroller - which in turn contains a couple of labels, one image and a dynamic text view.

The text view can contain anything from a few characters to 2000 words - how can I automatically apply the relevant heights to the UITextView and the parent scroller?

I have got as far as the following -

```
//Set Scroller
[self.scrollerArticle setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollerArticle setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 750)];
[self.articleUITextView sizeToFit];
[self.articleUITextView layoutIfNeeded];
```

But don't know how to apply the sizetofit method to the scroller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this,

```
[self.scrollerArticle setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, CGRectGetMaxY(self.articleUITextView.frame))];
```

Comment: To add on this you should call the above line of code after the `sizeToFit` function is called, because you will get a new frame for the UITextView after using it.

Answer (score 1):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView and you should use content size after you set up a text to get the size:

```
self.articleUITextView.text = @"YOUR TEXT";
CGRect rec = self.articleUITextView.frame;
rec.size.height = self.articleUITextView.contentSize.height;
textView.frame = rec;
```

After that you can just chance contentSize of your scroll view.
If you want to use sizeWithFont: it works fine for UILabels but not necessary with UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the height of the content using the below method.

```
-(CGFloat)getContentHeight{

NSString *aMessage = @"My Name is ABC"; // Can be anything between 0 to 2000 chars

CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 9999);

// Use the font you are willing to use for TexTView.
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:MessageFontSize];
CGSize myStringSize = [aMessage sizeWithFont:textFont
                   constrainedToSize:maximumSize
                       lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

return myStringSize.height;
}
```

And then can set the ContentSize of Scrollview accordingly.